# Редирект с HTTP на HTTPS в IIS 8.5

Tags: https, iis, http-redirect

Установил Url Rewrite 2.0 и сделал по инструкции данный редирект. В веб конфиге
получилось так:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
       <rule name="HTTP to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:0}" />
        </rule>
  </rules>
```

Но возникает ошибка TOO MANY REDIRECTS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я обычно делаю так:

```
 <rule name="http_to_https" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
          <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="SeeOther" />
  </rule>
```

Comment: Тот же результат(

Comment: @АлексейМаликов тогда посмотрите, что tracing выдает http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules возможно у Вас зацикливание в зависимости от домена...